# Angular 10 configure proxy from localhost to domain for fix CORS

Tags: javascript, angular, cors

I want make a GET request from my application angular to an API.
my application is on (localhost:4200).

When I request i use this URL

```
 return this.http
      .get<parameter>('https://sub.staging.company.com/application/action/getParams')
```

but I have a CORS errors like below :

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
```

For avoid this error, I created a proxy.conf.js

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: ["/application/action"],
    target: "https://sub.staging.company.com",
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
  },
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

But I have always this error and the proxy doesn't work.

How I can fix my problem ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Shouldn’t target be a fully qualified url? Add https://

Comment: this url is not real.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to proxy from a location on the same domain as your dev server. The browser still sees `https://sub.staging.company.com/application/action/getParams` as a cross domain request. You need to make a local call to /application/action/getParams and then the proxy will get it from `https://sub.staging.company.com/`

Answer (score -1):

To facilitate your development locally and assuming you're using Google Chrome, a Chrome extension like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino?hl=en) should do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Use have to implement it on backend too...

Like for node.js
`npm i cors`
then in `index.js`(root) file

```
const cors = require('cors');
    const corsOptions = {
      origin: 'http://example.com',
      optionsSuccessStatus: 200
    }
app.use(cors(corsOptions);
```

Comment: This answer lacks clarity.

Comment: I was on mobile...edited on desktop, if you read now maybe it will reduce readability issue....Why you think this answer is wrong??? It's prefect isn't it?